# error: expected unqualified-id before string constant extern "C" in unistd.h file

Tags: gcc, mingw, unistd.h

I am compiling the charmm++ Molecular Modelling program, but I see an error pointing to the unistd.h file that looks like:

```
/*  DUMMY unistd.h for netlrts-win32 build */
/*
    for example:
    xi-scan.C which is automatically generated by flex needs this header
    file
*/

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{

}
#endif

  int isatty (int );
```

The compiler is mingw's gcc. What is wrong?

Comment: What do you have in your source code before the `#include`?

Comment: several other includes, any way I realize few minutes ago that the included was A DUMMY version, overwrote it and now is compiling probably in an hour I have another issue, thanks anyway